# Optimize splitting column of lists into separate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been looking into splitting a column made up of lists into separate columns. I have a solution, but it is very slow.

I have the following pandas dataframe

```
|basket                             |
|['two apple','A banana']           |
|['Red pear','A banana']            |
|['two apple','A banana','Red pear']|
```

Which I would like to transform into the following dataframe.

```
|basket                             |two apple|A banana|Red pear|
|['two apple','A banana']           |1        |1       |0       |
|['Red pear','A banana']            |0        |1       |1       |
|['two apple','A banana','Red pear']|1        |1       |1       |
```

I have the following code, after already creating the columns I needed:

```
for index,row in enumerate(df.basket):
    if index>0 and index%10000==0:
        print(index/len(df.baskets),' percent complete')
    for n,col in enumerate(df.columns):
        for pattern in row:
            if col == pattern:
                df[col,index]=1
                break
```

With the number of rows I have this is taking forever and I was hoping to find a more efficient way of populating the columns, even if I have to create them from the column of lists.

Comment: I don't know if this will be faster, but… instead of doing three substring searches per row, what if you first converted each row into a list (e.g., `df.basket.str[1:-1].apply(ast.literal_eval)`), and then you could just do do `df[pattern, index] = 1` in the loop?

Comment: However, a better solution might be to transform the file into a CSV with the `||` and `[]` stripped off before importing into Pandas in the first place. Then you're doing a much more standard transformation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`MultiLabelBinarizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(mlb.fit_transform(df['basket']),
                  columns=mlb.classes_, 
                  index=df.index))
print (df)
                            basket  A banana  Red pear  two apple
0            [two apple, A banana]         1         0          1
1             [Red pear, A banana]         1         1          0
2  [two apple, A banana, Red pear]         1         1          1
```